# Aspectos na Geração de Logs de Erros por XML

Tags: c#, xml, exceção, log

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em C# que utiliza um banco de dados SQL Server, essa aplicação é disponibilizada através de um servidor de aplicações virtualizadas, eu não tenho acesso direto ao banco e nem ao servidor de aplicações.

Pretendo criar uma maneira de *logar* todos os erros da aplicação para que posteriormente eu possa verificá-los e corrigi-los, se for possível.

Consegui fazer isso da seguinte maneira:

```
// Fontes
// http://www.macoratti.net/13/07/c_excep.htm
// https://tiesontrowbridge.com/code/using-linq-to-easily-serialize-an-exception-to-xml

// Classe que executa a aplicação (Program.cs)
static void Main()
{
    // define o modo de tratamento dos erros não manipulados
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new frmMenu());
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Classe que serializa Exception (ExceptionXElement.cs)
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class ExceptionXElement : XElement
{
    public ExceptionXElement(Exception exception)
        : this(exception, false)
    { ; }

    public ExceptionXElement(Exception exception, bool omitStackTrace)
        : base(new Func<XElement>(() =>
        {
            XElement root = new XElement(exception.GetType().ToString());

            if (exception.Message != null)
            {
                root.Add(new XElement("Message", exception.Message));
            }

            if (!omitStackTrace && exception.StackTrace != null)
            {
                root.Add(
                    new XElement("StackTrace",
                        from frame in exception.StackTrace.Split('\n')
                        let prettierFrame = frame.Substring(6).Trim()
                        select new XElement("Frame", prettierFrame))
                    );
            }

            if (exception.Data.Count > 0)
            {
                root.Add(
                        new XElement("Data",
                        from entry in exception.Data.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                        let key = entry.Key.ToString()
                        let value = (entry.Value == null) ? "null" : entry.Value.ToString()
                        select new XElement(key, value))
                );
            }

            if (exception.InnerException != null)
            {
                root.Add(new ExceptionXElement(exception.InnerException, omitStackTrace));
            }

            return root;
        })())
    { ; }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Classe que representa o formulário principal de aplicação (frmMenu.cs)
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class frmMenu : Form
{
    public frmMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // assina o evento para tratar exceções não manipuladas
        Application.ThreadException += 
            new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    }

    private void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionXElement logException = new ExceptionXElement(e.Exception);
        logException.Save(@"D:\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy_HH-mm-ss") + ".xml");
        Close();
    }

    private void frmMenu_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int dividendo = 15, divisor = 0, resultado;
        resultado = dividendo / divisor; // linha 25
        Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", dividendo, divisor, resultado);
    }
}
```

A saída ficou assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<System.DivideByZeroException>
  <Message>Tentativa de divisão por zero.</Message>
  <StackTrace>
    <Frame>frmMenu.frmMenu_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) na frmMenu.cs:linha 25</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnShown(EventArgs e)</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Windows.Forms.Form.CallShownEvent()</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)</Frame>
    <Frame>System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()</Frame>
  </StackTrace>
</System.DivideByZeroException>
```

As minhas duvidas são as seguinte:

- Está é a maneira correta de *logar* todos os erros da aplicação?
- Existe alguma contra indicação de utilizar esse método?
- Como devo exibir a mensagem de erro para os usuários no método `Application_ThreadException`? Algo bem genérico ou mais específico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Esta é a maneira correta de logar todos os erros da aplicação?

Não existe uma maneira absoluta e correta para obter o estado da pilha da sua aplicação. Essa é uma das formas, e achei muito interessante como você fez pra resolver.

Não necessariamente você precisa gerar um XML para obter os erros. Poderia ter escrito a pilha direto em um arquivo de texto, sem formatação, já que é apenas você que vai conferir e nenhum processamento adicional será feito na massa de dados.

## Existe alguma contra indicação de utilizar esse método?

Aqui você gera um arquivo XML para cada exceção obtida na sua aplicação:

```
private void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    ExceptionXElement logException = new ExceptionXElement(e.Exception);
    logException.Save(@"D:\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy_HH-mm-ss") + ".xml");
    Close();
}
```

O único problema dela é se algum tipo de exceção que você tiver ficar muito recorrente, a quantidade de arquivos aumentará muito, além do que não é uma maneira muito eficiente de filtrar os erros pelo conteúdo dele.

Considere mandar as exceções para o Log de Eventos do Windows, lugar este em que você pode filtrar os erros através de uma série de critérios:

```
private void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MeuSistema", e.Exception.StackTrace,                  
                                   System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
}
```

## Como devo exibir a mensagem de erro para os usuários no método `Application_ThreadException`? Algo bem genérico ou mais específico?

Depende do perfil geral do seu usuário. Se for uma aplicação mais técnica, voltada para um perfil de usuário mais exigente, o correto é a mensagem ser bem específica. Caso contrário, não há necessidade.

Comment: considerando sua resposta, creio que não terei problemas com esse método, tentei fazer alguns testes com o `EventLog`, porém pelo que notei ele precisa de privilégios de administrador para funcionar, e isso infelizmente não conseguirei, mas seria uma opção legal de se usar também

Answer (score 1):

Repetindo uma frase já bem conhecida: **não existe bala de prata.**

Tratamento de erros, bem como um log, é um caso particular dos seus softwares. Por exemplo, meu conselho pro seu cenário é avaliar os tipos de erros que podem ocorrer. Muitas fábricas de sofware tem "bibliotecas de conhecimento" com os erros já conhecidos e suas causas.

Então,elas adicionam ao software, códigos próprios para esse erro e usam esses códigos nos logs para poder prever qual a solução vão usar, somente pelo tipo de erro. Assim diminuem o trabalho de análise dos erros.

A forma de logar propriamente dita é a mesma, talvez com um sistema um pouco mais complexo, que tenta repositórios em camadas:

- Tentar enviar automaticamente o log para mim
- Se não funcionar, tentar guardar em um arquivo de log que tambem guarda a pilha de variáveis do contexto onde ocorreu o erro (assim posso adiantar um debug parcial de valores nulos)
- Se não funcionar, usa o log do Windows/Linux.

Assim, você tem algumas vantagens:

- Qualquer atendente pode propor uma solução ao cliente sem ter que parar um programador, desde que o erro seja conhecido. E você não precisa parar um programador.
- Você não precisa que um cliente report um erro, ele é enviado para você e você pode agir de forma proativa.

Desvantagem:

- Preparar o componente de logs para lidar com esses códigos de erro dá trabalho.
- Manter o conhecimento sobre os erros e soluções organizado de forma que se possa usar, dá trabalho e exige disciplina.

Comment: essa abordagem seria interessante se fosse um sistema grande e com uma equipe de desenvolvedores, porém no meu caso é uma aplicação pequena, com um número pequeno de usuários e com um único desenvolvedor... eu, rsrs

Comment: Entao tenta prever inicialmente algumas coisas simples como, o tipo de erro que você quer logar, os erros que podem ocorrer nos lugares que você está logando e se você quer entrar em ação antes ou depois de ser avisado do erro. Dai fica mais fácil prever como você vai escrever seus logs e qual tipo de log usar.

Comment: essa maneira que encontrei pega os erros de qualquer parte da aplicação a partir do momento que o `Form` principal é exibido, a quantidade de erros provavelmente será pequena e serão na sua maioria erros de lógica, como um que encontrei através de um *log*, tentei usar o `TextBox.Substring(0, 2)` sem antes verificar se o `TextBox` estava preenchido